# Api Search Group by RT

Tags: api, rest, twitter

if I get a tweet with RT,[The Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) returns me each RT tweets are, as, the question is: **How I can group the retweets and the api returns retweets grouped?** In other words, if a tweet has 100 RT that groups them in only 1

thank you!
Cheers
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Someone twitter staff say : "No, unfortunately the API does not offer the ability to collapse these Tweets down to a count. Sorry."

Regards
Bruno